# supervisor.config giving ERROR [unix_http_server]: command not found

Tags: django, supervisord, aws-code-deploy

I am using supervisor in my django project. Here is my supervisor.config file looks like

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock 
[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log 
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       
logfile_backups=10           
loglevel=info                
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid 
nodaemon=false               
minfds=1024                  
minprocs=200                 

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock 

[program:run_django]
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(ENV_DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)
command=/home/ubuntu/www/project-venv/bin/gunicorn project.wsgi:application -w 1 -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -t 300 --max-requests=100
directory=/home/ubuntu/www/project/
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/www/project/logs/django_stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/www/project/logs/django_stderr.log
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

But I am getting the following error I try to deploy onto AWS EC2 instance through CodeDeploy

```
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f57f7cd1-e8f9-457e-8a00-ae66d494c068/d-SYX2MO8SP/deployment-archive/supervisor/default.conf:
line 1: [unix_http_server]: command not found
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f57f7cd1-e8f9-457e-8a00-ae66d494c068/d-SYX2MO8SP/deployment-archive/supervisor/default.conf:
line 3: [supervisord]: command not found
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f57f7cd1-e8f9-457e-8a00-ae66d494c068/d-SYX2MO8SP/deployment-archive/supervisor/default.conf:
line 13: [rpcinterface:supervisor]: command not found
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f57f7cd1-e8f9-457e-8a00-ae66d494c068/d-SYX2MO8SP/deployment-archive/supervisor/default.conf:
line 14: supervisor.rpcinterface_factory: command not found
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f57f7cd1-e8f9-457e-8a00-ae66d494c068/d-SYX2MO8SP/deployment-archive/supervisor/default.conf:
line 16: [supervisorctl]: command not found
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f57f7cd1-e8f9-457e-8a00-ae66d494c068/d-SYX2MO8SP/deployment-archive/supervisor/default.conf:
line 19: [program:run_django]: command not found
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f57f7cd1-e8f9-457e-8a00-ae66d494c068/d-SYX2MO8SP/deployment-archive/supervisor/default.conf:
line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f57f7cd1-e8f9-457e-8a00-ae66d494c068/d-SYX2MO8SP/deployment-archive/supervisor/default.conf:
line 20:
`environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(ENV_DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)'
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: You are missing an `s` at the end of that line: `%(ENV_DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)s`.

Comment: what about other errors? command not found?

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: You appear to be trying to execute this config file as a script, not sure how or why.

Answer (score 0):

I have executed it as a script from the appspec.yml file.. I have included it in start_application.sh. Here is my sample start_application script which runs from appspec.yml file

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings supervisord -c /home/ubuntu/www/project/supervisor/default.conf
```